# Matplotlib Radiobutton doesn't work anymore after clf()

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, radio-button, interactive

I'm plotting data with more than 4 dimensions. To make visualizations easier, I also want to plot all possible 2D and 3D combinations of the different dimensions.

To do this, I want one figure and navigate through the different options with `RadioButtons`. Now, as I change from 2D to 3D, I need a different amount of axes, so I clear my entire figure and plot everything again, but then my `RadioButton` doesn't work anymore (though I plot it again after `clf()`):

```
    class TEST(object):


def __init__(self):      
    self.num2d = 6
    self.rows2d = 3
    self.cols2d = 2

    self.num3d = 4
    self.rows3d = 2
    self.cols3d = 2

    self.fig2 = plt.figure()
    self.add2dAxes = []

    for i in range(self.num2d):
        ii = 100*self.rows2d + 10*self.cols2d + i+1
        self.add2dAxes.append(plt.subplot(ii))
    self.add_dim = 2

    self.updatePlotAdd()

    def click_dim(dim):
        print dim
        if dim == "2D":
            self.updatePlotAdd2d()
        elif dim == "3D":
            self.updatePlotAdd3d()
        else:
            self.updatePlotAdd4d()
    self.radioDim.on_clicked(click_dim)
    self.fig2._my_btn = self.radioDim
    plt.show()

def updatePlotAdd2d(self):
    print "2D"
    self.add_dim = 2
    self.fig2.clf()
    self.add2dAxes = []
    for i in range(self.num2d):
        ii = 100*self.rows2d + 10*self.cols2d + i+1
        self.add2dAxes.append(plt.subplot(ii))   
    self.updatePlotAdd()
def updatePlotAdd3d(self):
    print "3D"
    self.add_dim = 3
    self.fig2.clf()
    self.add3dAxes = []
    for i in range(self.num3d):
        ii = 100*self.rows3d + 10*self.cols3d + i+1
        self.add3dAxes.append(plt.subplot(ii)) 
    self.updatePlotAdd()

def updatePlotAdd4d(self):
    print "4D"
    self.add_dim = 4
    self.fig2.clf()
    self.updatePlotAdd()

def updatePlotAdd(self):        
    print "updatePlotAdd"
    rax = plt.axes([0.01, 0.7, 0.08, 0.1], axisbg='grey')
    self.radioDim = RadioButtons(rax, ("2D", "3D","> 3D"), active=self.add_dim-2)
    self.fig2.canvas.draw()
```

This example shows how the axes change perfectly the first time you click the button, but from then on the button doesn't respond anymore.

Comment: Can you reduce this down to the _minimal_ version that will replicate the problem?  There is too much code here that in extraneous to your problem.  People are willing to help, but may not be willing to sort thorough that much clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that in your "updatePlotAdd", you are re-creating RadioButtons object but you did not assign event trigger to this new object.

How about making the private function "click_dim" as class member function and call that in updatePlotAdd?

```
def click_dim(self, dim):
    print dim
    if dim == "2D":
        self.updatePlotAdd2d()
    elif dim == "3D":
        self.updatePlotAdd3d()
    else:
        self.updatePlotAdd4d()
```

And adding one line to updatePlotAdd:

```
def updatePlotAdd(self):        
    print "updatePlotAdd"
    rax = plt.axes([0.01, 0.7, 0.08, 0.1], axisbg='grey')
    self.radioDim = RadioButtons(rax, ("2D", "3D","> 3D"), active=self.add_dim-2)
    self.radioDim.on_clicked(self.click_dim)
    self.fig2.canvas.draw()
```

Of course the same goes to init too

```
    self.radioDim.on_clicked(self.click_dim)
```

With these modifications, it seems to work as you expected in my console.